# Survey : Add Attachments type of answer?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, attachments

can i add a new Attachments type of answer to survey !?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No in fact (OOTB), you will have to use custom coding, perform list schema modification or create the custom list.